# Permission Based Authorization in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to use a custom permission based authentication where i have the users-Roles-Permissions tables defined. I need to restrict access based on the permissions - CustomerEdit,CustomerView,CustomerDelete etc.
I have already read [about role based access using custom attributes](http://www.jacopretorius.net/2010/01/permission-based-access-in-asp-net-mvc.html)
The problem I see with this is I have to decorate each controller action with the attribute.

Is there another method to do this?

Comment: You can also decorate the controller itself, rather than each individual action.

Comment: As @Jesse said, a standard way of doing this is to decorate the controller and simply add [AllowAnonymous] decorators to any actions that don't require authorization.

Answer (score 0):

Could look at Fluent Security http://www.fluentsecurity.net/getting-started  It is configurable in code

Comment: Fluent Security is a role-based authentication not permission based

Comment: He also talks about role based and not wanting to decorate. So I suggested fluent for that reason. I appreciate it isn't Permission based. He could perhaps have created Roles around the permissions and used it that way e.g Editor Role etc.